# Django form Integer array Field

Tags: arrays, django

I would like to use django forms to validate fields being Integer Array. What is the best way to achieve this ? I don't want to use a ChoiceField and I am not sure what is the easiest way to achieve this. Any suggestion in that matter ?

Answer (score 2):

For storing the array I would use a [django-picklefield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield) or a custom field like this:

```
from django.db import models

class IntArrayField(models.TextField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IntArrayField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value: 
            return None
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return value
        return [int(n) for n in value.split('|')]

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        if not value: 
            return None
        assert(isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple))
        return '|'.join(str(value))

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)
```

For validation you can use [clean_fieldname()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/):

```
def clean_fieldname(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['fieldname']
        # if <data is not an int array>:
        #    raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter an int array.")

        return data
```

And it's also good to have some JavaScript code to validate input and make entering an int array easier on your client side.